# Fourier Transformations

Tags: analysis, fourier-analysis, fast-fourier-transform

I am trying to calculate the fourier transform of $$\left(\frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{2\pi}}\right)^{1/2}e^{\frac{-x^2}{4\sigma^2}}$$

Attempt:
$\vert\psi(x) \vert^2 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi \sigma}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2\sigma^2}}$

Now $\hat{\psi}(k) = \frac{1}{\sigma2\pi}\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{ikx}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2\sigma^2}} =\frac{1}{\sigma2\pi}\int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{ikx-\frac{x^2}{2\sigma^2}}$

I don't know how to simplify this into $\delta$ expression.

Comment: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FourierTransformGaussian.html

Comment: I tried the question on Wolfram Alpha and the solution was $$\sqrt[4]{2\pi}\sqrt{1/\sigma}\delta(k)e^{-\frac{x^2}{4\sigma^2}}$$ but there were no explicit steps.

Comment: I have solved the problem